# Transfer Images between iPhone and Web Service

Tags: iphone, objective-c, wcf, web-services

Thanks in advance everyone!

Background:

I have a WCF web service running that is communicating with an iPhone app over SOAP.

The WCF web service method is expecting a byte[].

Problem:

Now I need to transfer images to and from the the iPhone app to the web service.  I have been manually creating the SOAP request and sending it to the web service using the NSURLConnection class.

How do I create the SOAP request to include the PNG image data that is to be received by the web service method as a byte[]?

Please feel free to post any questions you have, I know I have not included all the details.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are probably better off using a simple SOAP library to define the calls:

[How to access SOAP services from iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204465/how-to-access-soap-services-from-iphone)

Why reinvent the wheel?