# How do I make an iPhone application consume a WSDL service?

Tags: iphone, wsdl

Is there a tool to generate stubs for me, or a library to interact with a wsdl web service?

This is a generic question I know, but I'm looking for pointers of where to start.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access SOAP services from iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204465/how-to-access-soap-services-from-iphone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This existing question should help.

[How to Access Soap Services from the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204465/how-to-access-soap-services-from-iphone)

chris.

Answer (score 2):

I hope the link will help you.

http://sudzc.com/

Comment: You might want to add some explanation. This answer looks a lot like spam (I know it isn't).