# transfer an image to an iphone http

Tags: iphone, objective-c, data-transfer

I have setup a connection to a server and now I want to transfer images to the iPhone.    What's the best way to do this?  I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204465/how-to-access-soap-services-from-iphone) and I don't see a way to transfer anything other than xml.  I need images.  Thank You!

Comment: Does anyone have an example of this using nsurlconnection and is that the best way, or is something else better?

Comment: Bryan: Where is the image coming from?  Where do you want to use/save it on the phone?

Comment: It's coming from a web server, I send a http post and get back a MIME message with xml, file info, binaries.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example of transfering images from the web to the iphone:

```
id path = @"http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/65821548/summer2007_normal.jpg";
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
            UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data ];
```