# iPhone - calling SOAP services

Tags: iphone, web-services, soap

I'm learning how to consume web services for a student project using the iPhone.

The top answer from [How to access SOAP services from iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204465/how-to-access-soap-services-from-iphone) suggested using http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/ to consume services.

However, I've tried using http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/DWMLgen/wsdl/ndfdXML.wsdl for the WSDL, but it crashes the application.

Any thoughts?  I'm not sure if the problem is with the WSDL or with the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My experience with `wsdl2objc` is that it is immature at best. Apple's solutions (`WSMethodInvocation` and its kin) are little better despite their age. I wish there were some easy answer for you, but when you get down with it, my experience is you have two options:

- Hand write the SOAP calls. For simple services this is possible, and it is actually my preferred solution if I can get away with it.
- Wrap [gSOAP](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html)-generated code in ObjC++.

Your *best* option of course is to find a way to avoid SOAP and use a REST interface if you can possibly get one.

If you're experienced in SOAP, then you may want to help out the `wsdl2objc` framework. They have a laudable goal. I haven't tried out the 0.6 release they put out this week. Maybe it's much better now. If you're trying the 0.5 release, maybe try again.

I know you're a student, so your needs are different. As a professional, I avoid SOAP in Cocoa like the plague, and fall back to gSOAP when I can't avoid it. Luckily REST is becoming increasingly popular, so I usually can dodge the bullet one more time.

Comment: I'm about to try gSOAP. Have an issue with WSDL2OBJC where it uses insane amount of memory (checked in instruments) for parsing 15MB xml response. For this response it consumes more than 100MB and iPad application crashes from memory warning. It took me several hours to determine this.

Answer (score 4):

http://sudzc.com/

it will generate Obj c soap client. here u can get example and documentation of your webservice if u giving your wsdl url

Answer (score 0):

Using wsdl2objc can be relied only when your requests and responses will have simple types. When I used wsdl2objc for a service which had complex request types and responses, I came to know this.

I am planning to use gSOAP for this.