# soap webservices in iphone app , how?

Tags: iphone, web-services, soap

I am currently working on an iphone app which requires me to use soap webservices , so that i can load data like customer info in my iphone app . If anyone knows how to so so  then please tell me or anyone knows where are the tutorials or examples then redirect me .

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204465/how-to-access-soap-services-from-iphone

Comment: Go through this, Its very detail oriented Tutorial for All Kind of WebServices.. http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/76730-webservice-how-to.html

Answer (score 2):

http://sudzc.com/

it will generate Obj c soap client. here u can get example and documentation of your webservice if u giving your wsdl url

Answer (score 1):

You will need to read the the apple doc on the URL loading system and NSXMLParser.  Complex XML documents can be quite a pain to deal with using the NSXMLParser, but there's plenty of resources on the web and books about turing the XML into more usable data structures.  Erica Sadun's book, "The iPhone Developer's Cookbook" seems to have a good one (though I haven't personally used it).