# how to consume a WSDL web service in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, wsdl, wcf

I have a wcf web service which returns a wsdl response when I invoke the service.How can I consume a WSDL web service in iphone?

Comment: Answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204465/how-to-access-soap-services-from-iphone

Comment: There is no sample code about the linked project

Comment: The SO answer may not have sample code, but the project itself has a link to iphone sample code and compilation instructions on the home page. Don't see any reason that duncanwilcox should copy and paste that code here. If there's something specific about wsdl2objc that is causing problems, feel free to edit your question or start a new one.

Comment: @Jarret Hardie; Yes I saw the link about wsdl2objc and the sample codes but they are not a whole working project and I really don't know how to start that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have seen this before but:

http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/