# How to accessing WSDL on iPhone

Tags: iphone

I need to access WSDL webservice on iphone. Is there any way to use SOAP or HTTP to access .wsdl url on iPhone.

Please suggest.

Thanks
SD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use Hessian protocol instead of WSDL. It support .NET/JAVA as server side language  http://sourceforge.net/projects/hessiankit/ and documentation http://wiki.caucho.com/Hessian_-_Objective-C_2.0_Implementation

Answer (score 4):

http://sudzc.com/

it will generate Obj c soap client. From [sudzc.com](http://sudzc.com), you can get example and documentation of your webservice if you provide your wsdl url.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204465/how-to-access-soap-services-from-iphone/284532#284532) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204465/how-to-access-soap-services-from-iphone), [wsdl2objc](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/) looks like a great place to start.  It generates Objective-C code from a WSDL for calling SOAP services.