# How to send the encrypted string from iOS to .net

Tags: ios, objective-c, .net, encryption, aes

I am using the `AES` encryption using the below code,

```
NSString *encryptedString =  [AESCrypt encrypt:@"str" password:@"password"];
```

The same string is not decoded correctly in .net server. The code is being used in .net server is as below,

```
AesEncryption = new RijndaelManaged();
AesEncryption.KeySize = 256;
AesEncryption.BlockSize = 128;
AesEncryption.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
AesEncryption.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
string keyStr = "cGFWDwzc3dvcmQAAAAAAwzc3==";
string ivStr = "aEdcGFzc3dvcmQwzc3AvcmQAAAAA==";
byte[] ivArr = Convert.FromBase64String(keyStr);
byte[] keyArr = Convert.FromBase64String(ivStr);
AesEncryption.IV = ivArr;
AesEncryption.Key = keyArr;
```

Can you please help me on this.

Comment: I would suggest to use base64 encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below link: Add iOS files and implement the same provided in the header files and ask your .Net developer to work on the same.

https://github.com/Pakhee/Cross-platform-AES-encryption

Comment: That library is terrible. RNCryptor is a much better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try below code for EncodeToPercentEscapeString to encrypt you string.

```
-(NSString *) encodeToPercentEscapeString
{
    return (__bridge_transfer NSString *) CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                                            (CFStringRef) self,
                                                                            ((CFStringRef) @" !*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]"));
}

NSString *password = @"password_123";
NSString *encryptString = [password encodeToPercentEscapeString];
```

Answer (score 0):

We do have AES , SHA , MDM5 etc encryption techniques available in iOS to encrypt the data/strings for ensuring the security of data transmit over the air,

Specifically i prefer to use AES 256 encryption you can follow the tutorial for encryption of your string given in the URL : http://robnapier.net/aes-commoncrypto

Once you encrypted your string , you can send that to .net/ back end using web service.

To send the data to .net using web service the answer with 3 reputations in the question here : [Send parameters to a web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581010/send-parameters-to-a-web-service) will help you.

Comment: Hi,
Can i get the download link for that RNCryptor.

Answer (score 0):

For a starter, you mixes up iv and key:

```
                                        VVVVVV
byte[] ivArr = Convert.FromBase64String(keyStr);
byte[] keyArr = Convert.FromBase64String(ivStr);
                                         ^^^^^^
```