# How to call an exchange 2010 web service to make appointments?

Tags: web-services, exchange-server-2010

I would like to call an Exchange 2010 web service from a remote client such as an iPhone to book a meeting room / to know if a meeting room is available etc.

Does anyone has an example available please?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any easy to follow sample so this is just some information that might help you get started anyway.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa563060.aspx) page has a sample for creating an appointment in C#. So I'd say that's part of the answer, the other part is to find out how to use SOAP from your language of choice. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204465/how-to-access-soap-services-from-iphone) SO question discusses just this.