# how to call wcf service from Iphone

Tags: .net, iphone, wcf

I want to develop a system that a Iphone application can access my database through the wcf service. I am new wcf services and i want to know which service should i make (rest or ?) and why and they communicate with each other?

Answer (score 3):

WCF Services are at heart SOAP Web Services. So you should be able to use an iPhone SOAP client library. See [How to access SOAP services from iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204465/how-to-access-soap-services-from-iphone).

Comment: but what i think is that iphone sdk does not support SOAP messages.

Comment: Have a look at the link. It points you to http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/ which creates Objective C code for calling a SOAP endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out
http://knowledgebaseworld.blogspot.com/2010/06/calling-wcf-service-from-iphone.html

[Imran](http://knowledgebaseworld.blogspot.com)

Answer (score 0):

I have had to make an app hit both a vanilla wcf and a wcf with rest support and the rest support is the way to go.

With rest, it was easier to just generate a standard web request in the app and get back XML that fed an NSXmlParser. There was no crazy soap request building. But then again, i didnt write the non-rest wcf service so maybe it just had configuration issues which made it more difficult.

The wcf rest service I wrote used the wcf rest starter kit from http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/wcf-rest