# Calling WCF Service from iPhone

Tags: ios, wcf

I've begun looking into a new idea that would require me to call a WCF service from an iPhone application. This WCF service would have to be able to call a stored procedure in an SQL Server database. I think I can figure this out. Where I'm unsure, however, is whether or not I will be able to call this WCF service from the iPhone app.

I've done a bit of searching already, and I've found mostly confusing answers. I found this question ( [how to call wcf service from Iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227385/how-to-call-wcf-service-from-iphone) ), which leads to this post with the top answer basically being "Don't" ( [How to access SOAP services from iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204465/how-to-access-soap-services-from-iphone) ).

What is the easiest way to call a WCF service from an iPhone (sending it some data), if it's even possible?

Comment: Are you limited to SOAP or can you send/receive JSON from your WCF service calls? Check out AFNetworking (http://afnetworking.com), in the short term.

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is in the how to call wcf web services from iPhone.  Look at the response from IBhadelia and his blog - http://knowledgebaseworld.blogspot.com/2010/06/calling-wcf-service-from-iphone.html