# Application of 3rd party API to my iPhone App, specifically SOAP

Tags: iphone

Firstly i'm not a programmer but I am managing to work my way through developing my own iphone app for my photography business.  I store all of my photographs with a 3rd party who make their API available for public use.  I want to implement this API into my app.

I've spoken with the 3rd party and they have written all of the code on a windows based system and although they say its not tied to a windows platform i'm struggling to see or recognise any Objective-C commands within the API and so don't know where to start.  They've also told me that its a SOAP based web service.

I'm wondering if anyone can tell me if I should be using the NSURLConnection method?  My main desire would be to generate a UITable view of the photo categories I hold with the 3rd party as is the case with their own iphone app, which i should probably say is for members only so wouldn't suit my needs here.

I would really appreciate some assistance with this as i'd hate to have to result to paying a developer to build the app after falling at the last hurdle.

Many thanks
Steve

Answer (score 1):

At a very basic level, SOAP APIs are just a standard HTTP requests against specific webserver that return XML responses. That third party may have a Windows-specific client-side library to speed up the development for some clients, but since you are developing iPhone app, you can't use that library.

You have two options:
 - use `NSURLConnection` and `NSXMLParser` and directly talk to their webservers and parse the response yourself;
 - look for an iPhone SOAP library you can reuse. Since SOAP is an industry standard, there's nothing that prevents anyone from building iPhone-specific libraries. However, I personally am not aware of particular ones.

Hope that helps. It's not the best answer, but at least it might give you an idea what to look for around.

**Update**: Quick search for "iPhone SOAP library" revealed the [`wsdl2objc`](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/) project, though that one is rather old (not updated since 2009). There are other alternatives, listed in the [How to access SOAP services from iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204465/how-to-access-soap-services-from-iphone) SO question.

Apple also has a [Web Services Core Framework](http://developer.apple.com/internet/webservices/webservicescoreandcfnetwork.html), but there's not much documentation on using it with iPhone.

Comment: Cheers for the very quick response.  I'll take a look at your suggestions.  Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Look at a sample app code which has soap specific files here:
http://mtgr8-a3.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mtgr8-a3/trunk/nvObjects/soap-specific/

In your posting you have mentioned that the 3rd party provided public APIs. If so, can you provide the wsdl? I can covert it to ObjC with SOAP support for you. I am not using wsdl2objC, but something lot better. If it is public API, you don't have to pay me.

Comment: Thanks for the response and assistance.  The API is at the following URL: http://www.zenfolio.com/zf/help/api/examples/browser
I've just taken a look and the WSDL is present (zfapi.wsdl).  If it would help to just forward you the WSDL file i will.  Thanks again.

Comment: Got it. How do I send the source back to you?

Comment: The files are ready. You can pick it up by registering at http://www.mtgr8.com/Demo.php
Its complete xcode project with sample login sequence and GetPopularPhoto query along with a basic UI to show the list of photos.