# How to denf a Soap Requesrt in iPhone Objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm a newcomer to the iPhone world. I'm working on an application having a login page. I have to send the UIText value of the username and password values to the server with the help of SOAP. I am having no ideas regarding this.

Can you help me?

Comment: A SO-Search on `SOAP iPhone` returns some results, e.g. [how to access soap services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204465/how-to-access-soap-services-from-iphone).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204465/how-to-access-soap-services-from-iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres lots if material around on accessing web services if you dig a bit and those other stack overflow threads are good.

I'll also blow my own horn a bit here :-)

I have written a static library at http://drekka.github.com/dXml which does SOAP web services. If it's not what you are looking for the source code is useful to help you understand how you can go about it.

I haven't gone into the security side too much here, but will eventually plan to add full ws-security to the api. At the moment it only does basic user name password authentication.