# Writing input for .NET web services 

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone web services. I need to get data from .NET web server. For that my soap message is:

```
NSString *xml = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<MortgageGetLoanOfficerInfo><PhoneNumber>919703661366</PhoneNumber></MortgageGetLoanOfficerInfo>"];

    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
    @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
    "<soap:Body>\n"
    "<GenericAndroidMethod xmlns=\"Mortgage\">\n"
    "<methodName>MortgageGetLoanOfficerInfo</methodName>"
    "<xmlParam>%@</xmlParam>"
    "</GenericAndroidMethod>\n"
    "</soap:Body>\n"
    "</soap:Envelope>\n",xml
    ];
```

But I did not get a response.

When checking in charles web debugging proxy, it will show [like this](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/2f953a589e.gif).

But I need to pass `<MortgageGetLoanOfficerInfo><PhoneNumber>919703661366</PhoneNumber></MortgageGetLoanOfficerInfo>` as a single string. How can I do this? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolve My problem By using CDDATA.

```
<xmlParam><![CDATA[<MortgageGetLoanOfficerInfo><PhoneNumber>919703661366</PhoneNumber></MortgageGetLoanOfficerInfo>]]></xmlParam>
```

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to successfully make SOAP calls:

[How to access SOAP services from iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204465/how-to-access-soap-services-from-iphone)