# Android XML Rich Text Processing

Tags: android, xml, rss, xml-parsing, sax

I used the tutorial listed here to parse my XML:

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/05/simple-rss-reader-iii-show-details-once.html

The problem I am having is when I try to read in the XML description tag all I get is this:

[image: <]

The "<" symbol is where the description should go.  This is the feed I am reading: http://www.calvaryccm.com/rss/devos.ashx

Please help me solve my issue in getting the real text into the description. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is html encoded, you can use one of the following methods -- or if it is unencoded, you can surround the content in CDATA tags.

```
Spanned spannedContent = Html.fromHtml(htmlString);
textView.setText(spannedContent, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

or

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.aWebView);
String htmlString = "<html><body>Some html</body></html>";
webview.loadData(htmlString, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Answer (score 2):

I just created an android project in eclipse using the code I downloaded from the site you listed above.  I only made one modification to the original sources. I changed line 33 in AndroidRssReader.java to read:

```
            URL rssUrl = new URL("http://www.calvaryccm.com/rss/devos.ashx");
```

The feed loads and parses fine.
[image]

The parsing error is the result of changes you made to the original sources.

Comment: What is supposed to happen is the link is clicked (EX: Bring Us Back) then it goes to a detail view with the title description and link.  The issue is in the detail view not the main view.

Comment: If you go back and look at the blog post where the sources came from quite a few people are leaving comments complaining that the parser doesn't work with richtext or html tags.  I'd suggest finding another example or contacting the original author to see if he/she has come up with a fix.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that I need to wrap my RSS tags in CDATA Tags as shown here:

[Writing input for .NET web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516471/help-needed-to-write-input-for-net-web-services)