# wsdl soap web services parsing in IPhone Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, wsdl

I want to parse wsdl web service 
like 
http://example.com/exampleMethod/AuthenticationService.svc?wsdl=wsdl0

in Iphone ,so please guide me for the above.
I m searching it desperately.

lots of Thanks for any help

Comment: See previous answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204465/how-to-access-soap-services-from-iphone

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access SOAP services from iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204465/how-to-access-soap-services-from-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

There is one way by which you can get the request format for that wsdl file.

Download [SoupUI Pro](http://dl.eviware.com/3_6_1/soapUI-Pro-3_6_1.dmg)

install it. Create a new project and give the specific wsdl file as input. Then it will shows the request format in the certain tab. You can User that request format to send the request.