# SOAP and XML Response Parsing Samples for iPhone/iPad?

Tags: xml, soap, ios4

After searching around for a while, I have been unable to find any helpful samples/tutorials on using a SOAP interface in an iPhone/iPad app. If someone knows of any good ones regarding SOAP and/or XML parsing of the response I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!
~KS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, well I've managed to get something working that is able to post and receive/view a response from a SOAP service in my iPhone app as of xcode 4.0.

http://abhicodehelp.blogspot.com/2010/12/handling-soap-with-iphone.html

I used bits of code from the above link in combination with some of my own exploration with regards on how to actually authenticate with a username and password which I've added below.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    NSURLCredential *myCreds = [[NSURLCredential alloc] initWithUser:@"**USERNAME**" password:@"**PASSWORD**" persistence:NO];

    [challenge.sender useCredential:myCreds forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    [myCreds release];
}
```

While old, the link below seemed to be a much more popular question when asked so im sure there are some more resources available that I didn't end up using.

[How to access SOAP services from iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204465/how-to-access-soap-services-from-iphone).

Hope this helps anyone with a similar question!
-Karoly

Comment: Parsing tutorial. It looks like that guy may have stolen it, though its a helpful tutorial regardless. http://www.xcode-tutorials.com/parsing-xml-files/

Comment: Useful info. to authenticate user/pass values