# iOS webservice xml help

Tags: iphone, mysql, ios, ipad, sqlite

i am trying to create an app that connects to a mysql database, downloads the records in the table for the user then displays them in a UITableview which can be drilled down with the data that as downloaded from the mysql database. I would also like the data to be stored locally in something like sqlite. The data would then be modified then uploaded back to the mysql database.

My questions is where do i start? I have read alot of posts on google and they say that its best to connect to a xml which acts as a middle man between the database and the app. How can i create this xml file? is it something that is generated every time the app is launched or something done daily on the server?

If anyone can help me out. i know its a very broad question so if someone can point me in the right direction im not asking someone to right this app just a hand as im lost.

Thanks,
Aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood you want a kind of ORM?
If so you can check for [Restkit](http://restkit.org/) and more specifically on the side of the object mapping system. It allows us to synchronize remote object/data locally with the coredata.
I have never used it, but I have seen a great tuto which talking about that here: [Advanced RestKit Development](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/advanced-restkit-development_iphone-sdk/) (However I think it works only with json messages).

I hope it'll help you in your reflection.

Answer (score 1):

I know others have mentioned links to libraries that let you connect to MySQL from iOS. I've not tried them myself but don't rule that out.

To answer your quest, you do not "create" the XML files. Web services are developed in a language, and written as applications. You would in essence need to write another application that runs on a server. That application would connect to your MySQL database. That application would also publish methods for getting at, and updating, data. By virtue of making your server a SOAP web service (in whatever platform), the data will be sent over the wire as XML.

Comment: JSON would be preferred, it's smaller, and easier to make. Especially if you're making the web service in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at XML Parser, Webservice, and Core Data tutorials.

[SOAP and XML Response Parsing Samples for iPhone/iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458138/soap-and-xml-response-parsing-samples-for-iphone-ipad)

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_4_iPhone_Core_Data_Tutorial_%28Xcode_4%29

That would be a good start, and I could give you some more material if you would like. As far as setting up your actual web service, I've never done that so I couldn't help you there.