# webservice soap for iphone

Tags: iphone, web-services, soap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access SOAP services from iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204465/how-to-access-soap-services-from-iphone)

I want to call webservice for xcode.
I have [wsdl](http://202.44.69.24/webservices/ws_registration.cfc/?wsdl).
What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

try this and view the tutorial.. very easy..

http://sudzc.com/