# Are there any native iOS solutions for communication with SOAP web service?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, soap

Is it true, there's no native built-in libs or frameworks for communicating with a web service via SOAP? There's some [Web Services Core framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/WebServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008090) that deals with SOAP but it's available only for mac os. All stack overflow [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204465/how-to-access-soap-services-from-iphone) mention about 3rd party libs for dealing with SOAP (CSoap and other)...

Currently, I'm looking for a wrapper API like "sendRequestWithMessage:" and "receiveResponseWithMessage:". I would prefer higher level API instead of manual construction of HTTP request, setting headers (length and etc), and maybe simplified XML construction.

Comment: Try to search stackoverflow. There are a lot of topics about consuming SOAP messages in iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SudzC.com](http://SudzC.com) generating files are not a library , it generates your classes based on your wsdl file, it generates purely objective c source code.

Comment: Thanks. I already "got my hands dirty" both with SudzC and with wsdl2objc. Have tested with simple wsdl -  http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL, both works as expected, however, SudzC has a lot more clear code and even generates documentation. So, I guess I will stick with SudzC. PS: hope its website will not get down :)