# WSDL webservices for iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios, web-services, wsdl, xcode4.3

I tried to work on wsdl web services for objective c, but i did n't find any good solution.
Any one help me with a sample application how to get wsdl data in to iPhone application.

Comment: Go through this, Its very detail oriented Tutorial for All Kind of WebServices.. http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/76730-webservice-how-to.html

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a number of third party projects for generating client code from a WSDL file. Have a look at this SO answer: [How to access SOAP services from iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/204465/4608)