# How to call WSDL with Method & Parameter?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, web-services, ipad, wsdl

Hi i'am new in xcode & objective-C

now i have application get data from server by xml

but if i want to change xml to webservice by WSDL with Method & Parameter
how i can do

ex. ws url

```
http://HOST:PORT/ExportingReportWebservice/ExportingReportWebservice?wsdl
```

Method name is getReport
Parameter is java.lang.String

SOAP Response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:getReportResponse xmlns:ns2="http://controller.exportingreportwebservice.lox.org/">
            <return>
                <exportId>4</exportId>
                <readFG>N</readFG>
                <receiverId>2711</receiverId>
                <referenceId>21</referenceId>
                <referenceName>???????????????????????? ?????????????????????????????????????????????</referenceName>
                <reportFullPath>http://10.3.24.202:8081/ExportingReportAdmin/Reports/55126a88-dcec-45d1-b156-e1eb9ab2b48e.pdf</reportFullPath>
                <reportName>55126a88-dcec-45d1-b156-e1eb9ab2b48e.pdf</reportName>
                <senderId>7615</senderId>
                <senderName>???????????????????????? ??????????????????</senderName>
                <sentDate>2012-05-23 10:40:01.0</sentDate>
                <subject>Report Surgical</subject>
            </return>
            <return>
                <exportId>8</exportId>
                <readFG>N</readFG>
                <receiverId>2711</receiverId>
                <referenceId>20</referenceId>
                <referenceName>????????????????????? ???????????????????????????</referenceName>
                <reportFullPath>http://10.3.24.202:8081/ExportingReportAdmin/Reports/691766e9-44eb-4ca9-9908-1b1846327acc.pdf</reportFullPath>
                <reportName>691766e9-44eb-4ca9-9908-1b1846327acc.pdf</reportName>
                <senderId>7615</senderId>
                <senderName>???????????????????????? ??????????????????</senderName>
                <sentDate>2012-05-23 10:41:28.0</sentDate>
                <subject>prime face user guide</subject>
            </return>
            <return>
                <exportId>13</exportId>
                <readFG>N</readFG>
                <receiverId>2711</receiverId>
                <referenceId>21</referenceId>
                <referenceName>???????????????????????? ?????????????????????????????????????????????</referenceName>
                <reportFullPath>http://10.3.24.202:8081/ExportingReportAdmin/Reports/c4f4f1fd-1c67-4bad-9447-f536fd2b46db.pdf</reportFullPath>
                <reportName>c4f4f1fd-1c67-4bad-9447-f536fd2b46db.pdf</reportName>
                <senderId>7615</senderId>
                <senderName>???????????????????????? ??????????????????</senderName>
                <sentDate>2012-05-23 11:21:23.0</sentDate>
                <subject>icefaces getting start</subject>
            </return>
        </ns2:getReportResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Thankyou verymucth

ps. sorry for my English skill.

Answer (score 1):

You can either write your own implementation using NSURL classes to connect to the webservice and use the NSXML to parse the received responses OR you can check out this thread ( [How to access SOAP services from iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204465/how-to-access-soap-services-from-iphone) ) and use one of the frameworks mentioned there.