# IOS - Connect to Webservice

Tags: ios, soap, service, web

ok there is no real way to connect to soap within ios5... sadly enough.

I cant really believe that things that take 3 lines of code in php,

```
$client = new SoapClient("scramble.wsdl");
print($mirror = $client->sendAndGetString("hello_world"));
```

need 366 lines of code in objective c? And that on a device that has one of the biggest number of ria's and web apps.
Kind of disappointing -

Are there any new libraries I am not aware of?

If I talk to our web developer team they maybe switch to another service type that is more supported by IOS.

What would be a alternative then?

Thanks

Comment: There are numerous ways to connect to SOAP on the iOS, just look at the related questions here for a hint. In general, the iOS SDK is a little lower level than, say, PHP or Python.

Comment: I found ways to load everything as xml... this cant be right. Also it   was 2 years old. Could you give me a link to an working example. Do you know libraries? thanks

Comment: See this question: [How to access SOAP services from iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204465/how-to-access-soap-services-from-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

The difference between dynamically typed languages such as PHP and statically typed languages such as Objective-C regarding RPC protocols is that while dynamic languages typically allows you to wrap "any" service in run-time by reflecting out their metadata (e.g. WSDL), statically typed languages normally requires a code generation step before the compilation phase.

Two popular code generators seem to be [wsdl2objc](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/) and [sudz-c](http://sudzc.com/). See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204465/how-to-access-soap-services-from-iphone).

Regarding alternatives, I have good experience using both JSON and XML-RPC, as well as the more schema-oriented [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) and [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) [(ObjC)](https://github.com/rickardp/protobuf-objc).

Comment: Thanks Krumelur. The link you mentioned above I actually already had known. I tried wsdl2objc and sudz-c. both create a big chunk of classes. Which arent working out off the box anyway. The whole SOAP thing really shouldnt be used on iPhone. Most of the blog threads I have checked out today went nowhere. Solutions aren't really usable to my opinion. I will try json plus php logic on the server side as it looks a bit more nativ usable by ios.

Answer (score 0):

I've written several tutorials about using SOAP services in iOS with Wsdl2Objc: http://brismith66.blogspot.com/search/label/iPhone%20Development