# How to pass a parameter to soap web service from iphone?

Tags: iphone, web-services

I want call a web service with parameter from my iphone app.

The parameter is a string and where and  how I have to specify the parameter calling the web service using xml or whatever it is.

Please tell me if somebody knows about it. I want to send a state name to the web service.

please help me to solve this issue.

```
NSString *soapMessage = 
    [NSString stringWithFormat:
     @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
     "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
     "<soap:Body>"
     "<stateWiseHospitalName  xmlns=\"http://ws.centricare.org\" />"
     "</soap:Body>"
     "</soap:Envelope>"

     ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply :

```
"<stateWiseHospitalName  xmlns=\"http://ws.centricare.org\" />"
"<first parameter>value</first parameter> <second parameter>value</second parameter>
...... "
"</stateWiseHospitalName> /n "
```

Answer (score -1):

iOS doesn't have any built-in support for SOAP, so you may want to [find a library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/204465/643383) to help with creating and interpreting SOAP messages. If you're comfortable doing that yourself and just need help to post the message to a server, you can use NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection for that.

Answer (score -1):

I don't recommend using SOAP. Been there, done that, it's a gruelling experience.

I prefer using JSON for web services. The folks at http://www.three20.info have a comprehensive framework to dealing with it.