# Creating SOAP request manually - server receives null string as an argument

Tags: java, string, web-services, soap, ios6

So, the problem is, I've set up (on localhost) a Java Webservice server that uses Endpoint.publish to publish the service and it's WSDL, and iOS 6 project that tries to send a hand-written SOAP request to localhost server.

I have a "getCostForName" function that receives String and returns int. 
On the iOS side, here's what I'm doing:

```
{
    NSString *soapMessage = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns=\"http://endpoints/\" >"
    "<soap:Body>"
    "<getCostForName>"
    "<name>Gdansk</name>"
    "</getCostForName>"
    "</soap:Body>"
    "</soap:Envelope>";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:9999/ws/wycieczka/"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue: @"http://localhost:9999/ws/wycieczka/" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if( theConnection )
    {
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [webData setLength: 0];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [webData appendData:data];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"ERROR with theConenction");
    [connection release];
    [webData release];
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);
    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",theXML);
    [theXML release];
```

}

On the Java side, it looks like this:

```
    @Override
    public Integer getCostForName(String name) {
        System.out.println("getCostForName received:" + name);
        //Calculate the cost for a given name...
    }
```

The webservice interface is defined by following annotations:

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style=SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
```

The webservice is hosted using following endpoint publish method:

```
Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:9999/ws/wycieczka", new WycieczkaServiceImpl());
```

On Java's side, here's what I get:

```
Nov 19, 2012 11:08:52 AM com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter fixQuotesAroundSoapAction
getCostForName received:null
WARNING: Received WS-I BP non-conformant Unquoted SoapAction HTTP header: http://localhost:9999/ws/wycieczka/
```

So, as you can see, server receives null string. And I can't figure out why exactly can't I transmit a String over webservice :( So, could anybody, please, tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I wouldn't use SOAP unless I absolutely had to, because its just so complex. Why not make a RESTful web service instead, with something like Apache Jackrabbit (http://jackrabbit.apache.org/)?

Comment: It's not possible to change the server. It's SOAP, and it'll stay SOAP. Transition to RESTful is not possible at all, as it's not my thing to decide what method we're going to use. My colleague chose that, and it's impossible to change his mind, and that's why I'm stuck with SOAP.

Answer (score 1):

I think its probably because you're missing the SOAP header in the request, though I would really avoid doing this via String concatenation. SOAP is a very complex protocol, and it needs a proper client implementation. Try this...

[How to access SOAP services from iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204465/how-to-access-soap-services-from-iphone)

Comment: I added a <soap:Header></soap:Header> to the request, however the result is still the same.

I tried using sudzc, however i had the exact same problem. I'll try using wsdl2objc, however I don't know whether that'll work :(

Comment: Nope, wsdl2OBJC didn't work either. as there's not enough space, here's what I've got: pasted into pastebin: [link](http://pastebin.com/Xn8a9jqx)

Comment: Maybe it would help to confirm that the SOAP service works first with something like SOAP UI (http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/files/)

Comment: SOAP service by itself works. I have a typical HelloWorld service that receives nothing and returns String: "hello world!"

I was able to sucessfully receive that string manually and by sudzc

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using ksopa2 ver3 but I was not using a hand written SOAP I used auto generated classed from www.wsdl2code.com. There was a line

soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;

in the java file for that was generated for my EndPoint. I changed that to false and it worked fine after that.

Akil

Answer (score 0):

Per section 6.1.1 of the SOAP 1.1 spec, the SOAPAction HTTP header must have double quotes surrounding the URI-reference (if present).

That's the reason why are you getting this warning:

```
WARNING: Received WS-I BP non-conformant Unquoted SoapAction HTTP header: http://localhost:9999/ws/wycieczka/
```

Should be:

```
 [theRequest addValue: @"\"http://localhost:9999/ws/wycieczka/\"" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
```