# asp.net wsdl consumpution in iphone

Tags: iphone, asp.net, wsdl

i want to consume `wsdl services` on iphone created in `asp.net` , before this i was using php and it was very eady to hit the URL and get data but now I don't know how to consume these webservices i searched on stackoverflow some guys are reffering already created components some are suggesting example of very simple compoenents so please help , what is the best way to consume `WSDL webservices in iphone` 
my url is like that

```
   http://test.com/LumiaSurvesdsdsdsy/sdsddsdia.svc?wsdl
```

Comment: you have found already solutions, the "best" is subjective, the accepted answer must meet your imagination and those who is writing, is nothing with clear, objecive answerable question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This existing question and answer will provide the details, WSDL services are the same as SOAP Services:

[How to access SOAP services from iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204465/how-to-access-soap-services-from-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

You are actually discouraged to consume `SOAP` web services from mobile devices as the overhead is way too big, so the advice is to use `REST` services. If you insist on consuming `SOAP` services, then you can try out the [wsdl2objc](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/) generator to build the proxy classes from your `wsdl`, but keep in mind that this may be a bit buggy and some fixes might be required.

Comment: +1 - why the downvote? i survived beautifully on WSDL2OBJC as per @graver until I moved over to REST services with JSON as they are less bulky. I never found bugs in WSDL2OBJC though just aslong as you run the tool over the wsdl whom's web method's params and return value use strongly typed classes