# Wrong data returned from NSURLResponse when trying to invoke web service method

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, tomcat, httpresponse

im rather new at this.. i got a tomcat server running and i have a web service method there that when invoked, returns a string. when i try to use

```
NSOperationQueue *backgroundQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

// URL Request

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:
 [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8080/WebServiceTutorialClient/sampleHelloProxy/Input.jsp?method=18"]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
// Send Request


[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:backgroundQueue
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
                           NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                           NSLog(@"%@", result);
                       }];
```

i just get the contents of the page, rather than the string the method was supposed to return. this prolly looks silly but i have no idea how to get that string. i do get the response successfully (when i NSLog reponse object i see that), but i assume it just contains the html data i get returned anyway.

how do i invoke the method from my tomcat server, getting the string returned to me? thanks alot for your time!

edit: this is the logged response:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Inputs</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>Inputs</H1>


<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="Result.jsp" TARGET="result">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="method" VALUE="18">
<BR>
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Invoke">
<INPUT TYPE="RESET" VALUE="Clear">
</FORM>


</BODY>
</HTML>
```

edit 2: this is the hello service diagram. how do i invoke by code a specific method?
[image: hello service]

Comment: Rob - editing main post now with the logged result. thanks for your comment!

Comment: Rob - when i go to the address on the code, i get to see exactly what the html says - i see a button with 'invoke' and 'clear', with the titles. when i hit 'invoke', i get opened another tab, with title 'result' and the text it is supposed to return. does this help figuring what my problem is?

Comment: Rob - it seems you were right, i found the address for my hello service at "http://localhost:8080/WebServiceTutorial/services/Hello". however, how do i invoke a specific method? i will post an image describing what i mean

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29420/discussion-between-rob-and-zephyer)

Answer (score 0):

As we discussed in chat, the code in the original question conflates the HTML user interface for testing a web service with the actual web service itself. Your sample code is making a HTTP request of the HTML page that is used for testing the web service. You really probably want to interact directly with your web service.

Having said that, using SOAP/WSDL web service interface makes the process pretty complicated. In the [How to access SOAP services from iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204465/how-to-access-soap-services-from-iphone) discussion, I would agree with schwa's conclusion: "don't". More to the point, if you're writing a new web service, some REST service delivering JSON is going to be much easier to work with. Or, if you're stuck with the SOAP-based service, you could write a new web service that consumes the SOAP service and delivers JSON.

If you really want an iOS app to interact directly with the SOAP service defined by a particular WSDL, it seems like there are two approaches: First, you could use one of the source code generators (like [sudzc.com](http://sudzc.com)). I was underwhelmed by this class of solution out there. Second, you could use a tool like [Soap UI](http://www.soapui.org) to manually create the `XML` for a request, and then use that as a template from iOS.

So, I tried out the latter approach:

1. You mentioned that you followed [the tutorial](http://www.roseindia.net/webservices/buildingsimplewebservice.shtml). I actually found [this article](http://javapapers.com/web-service/axis2-web-service-using-eclipse/) to be more useful in getting the web service going, but if you had success with the former, that's fine.
2. I created a web service, `HelloTest`, with a `Hello` class with a single method, `sayHello`, that takes one parameter, the `name`, and returns `"Hello " + name`:

   ```
   package com.tutorial;

   public class Hello {
       public String sayHello(String name){
           return "Hello " + name;
       }
   }
   ```
3. I had Eclipse generate the WSDL for me. The particulars are uninteresting, but it's not entirely dissimilar from yours:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ns1="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://tutorial.com" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" targetNamespace="http://tutorial.com">
       <wsdl:documentation>
           Please Type your service description here
       </wsdl:documentation>
       <wsdl:types>
           <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tutorial.com">
               <xs:element name="sayHello">
                   <xs:complexType>
                       <xs:sequence>
                           <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="name" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                       </xs:sequence>
                   </xs:complexType>
               </xs:element>
               <xs:element name="sayHelloResponse">
                   <xs:complexType>
                       <xs:sequence>
                           <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                       </xs:sequence>
                   </xs:complexType>
               </xs:element>
           </xs:schema>
       </wsdl:types>
       <wsdl:message name="sayHelloRequest">
           <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:sayHello"/>
       </wsdl:message>
       <wsdl:message name="sayHelloResponse">
           <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:sayHelloResponse"/>
       </wsdl:message>
       <wsdl:portType name="HelloPortType">
           <wsdl:operation name="sayHello">
               <wsdl:input message="ns:sayHelloRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:sayHello"/>
               <wsdl:output message="ns:sayHelloResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:sayHelloResponse"/>
           </wsdl:operation>
       </wsdl:portType>
       <wsdl:binding name="HelloSoap11Binding" type="ns:HelloPortType">
           <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
           <wsdl:operation name="sayHello">
               <soap:operation soapAction="urn:sayHello" style="document"/>
               <wsdl:input>
                   <soap:body use="literal"/>
               </wsdl:input>
               <wsdl:output>
                   <soap:body use="literal"/>
               </wsdl:output>
           </wsdl:operation>
       </wsdl:binding>
       <wsdl:binding name="HelloSoap12Binding" type="ns:HelloPortType">
           <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
           <wsdl:operation name="sayHello">
               <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:sayHello" style="document"/>
               <wsdl:input>
                   <soap12:body use="literal"/>
               </wsdl:input>
               <wsdl:output>
                   <soap12:body use="literal"/>
               </wsdl:output>
           </wsdl:operation>
       </wsdl:binding>
       <wsdl:binding name="HelloHttpBinding" type="ns:HelloPortType">
           <http:binding verb="POST"/>
           <wsdl:operation name="sayHello">
               <http:operation location="sayHello"/>
               <wsdl:input>
                   <mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
               </wsdl:input>
               <wsdl:output>
                   <mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
               </wsdl:output>
           </wsdl:operation>
       </wsdl:binding>
       <wsdl:service name="Hello">
           <wsdl:port name="HelloHttpSoap11Endpoint" binding="ns:HelloSoap11Binding">
               <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/HelloTest/services/Hello.HelloHttpSoap11Endpoint/"/>
           </wsdl:port>
           <wsdl:port name="HelloHttpSoap12Endpoint" binding="ns:HelloSoap12Binding">
               <soap12:address location="http://localhost:8080/HelloTest/services/Hello.HelloHttpSoap12Endpoint/"/>
           </wsdl:port>
           <wsdl:port name="HelloHttpEndpoint" binding="ns:HelloHttpBinding">
               <http:address location="http://localhost:8080/HelloTest/services/Hello.HelloHttpEndpoint/"/>
           </wsdl:port>
       </wsdl:service>
   </wsdl:definitions>
   ```
4. I used [Soap UI](http://www.soapui.org) to take the WSDL and create an example request.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tut="http://tutorial.com">
       <soap:Header/>
       <soap:Body>
           <tut:sayHello>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <tut:name>Rob</tut:name>
           </tut:sayHello>
       </soap:Body>
   </soap:Envelope>
   ```

   It may have been unique to my configuration, but I had to play around with the SOAP envelope generated by Soap UI, replacing the SOAP 1.2 URI:

   ```
   http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope
   ```

   with a SOAP 1.1 URI:

   ```
   http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
   ```

   I also, for purposes of example, replaced the `?` placeholder with "Rob" (as I wanted my web service to say hello to me).
5. Anyway, I now can submit that request in iOS via the following Objective-C code:

   ```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8080/HelloTest/services/Hello"];
   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

   NSString *filename = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"request1" ofType:@"xml"];
   NSData *requestBodyData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filename];
   request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData;

   [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
   [request addValue:@"http://tutorial.com" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
   [request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

   NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
   [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                      queue:queue
                          completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                              NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
                              if (data)
                              {
                                  NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
                              }
                          }];
   ```

   Clearly, how you create the `NSData` with the request may vary (to keep this "simple" I put the XML of the SOAP request into a text file called `request1.xml` and included that in my bundle). Likewise, how you initiate the request may (I used [`NSURLConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method, [`sendAsynchronousRequest`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-SW10)). But hopefully this gives you an idea of how you'd send a manually created SOAP request.
6. That generates a response that looks like (I've prettified it, but this is the response):

   ```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <soapenv:Body>
           <ns:sayHelloResponse xmlns:ns="http://tutorial.com">
               <ns:return>Hello Rob</ns:return>
           </ns:sayHelloResponse>
       </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>
   ```

   You can then parse this answer with an XML parser, such as [`NSXMLParser`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

For me, the "take home" message is that I wouldn't do this unless I absolutely had to. I think that `JSON` web services are just as easy to create, and it's far easier to consume their responses in iOS.