# WSDL SOAP web service integraion in iOS

Tags: ios, magento, soap, wsdl

Currently i am developing new iOS application which POINT to **MAGENTO WSDL SOAP** web service.

After lots of searching i found the **LogNMagento-master** library.

But still i got wrong response.

So any one integrated magento wsdl api or there are any solution or tutorial please provide the link.

Thanks.

Comment: http://sudzc.com/ try this will convert WSDL to SOAP client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem in calling method from LogNMagento.

I resolved issue by changing style of method calling.

Comment: What do you mean by style of method calling, could help with some code snippet ? Even m facing the same issue, looking for v2 api's .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [service](http://sudzc.com/). You have to link or upload your wsdl and it creates a folder with the entire example project. Unfortunatly now it requires a 30$ year subscription.

Also check [wdsl2objc](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/)
and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204465/how-to-access-soap-services-from-iphone).