# How to de-serialize an object in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, wcf, nsmutablearray, generic-list

I have an error when I try to make a wcf method work. One of the parameters are NSMutableArray and the Object type is TypeClass. I checked everything with the NSMutableArray and everything seems fine.

My code for the parameter is:

```
NSData *myPostData = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"parameter1\":\"%@\"}",mynsmutablearraylist] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableData *myMutablePostData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:myPostData];
```

The parameter type in wcf is like List< TypeClass>.

I can see the values of the object and keys of the mynsmutablearraylist. But I can't understand why it doesn't work.

This wcf method works for the Win8 metro application but I can't make it work for IOS.

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The
>   exception message is 'The formatter threw an exception while trying to
>   deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to
>   deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:typeclass. The
>   InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the
>   object of type
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[ServiceOfMine.Entities.TypeClass,
>   ServiceOfMine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]. Encountered invalid character '
>   
>   '.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.'. See server logs
>   for more details. The exception stack trace is:

**Added Info:**

When I test the parameters with the exactly the same values , it works fine. The part of the Request in SOAPUI:

```
> >....
> >      <tem: parameter4>parvalue</tem: parameter4>
> >      < tem: typeclass>
> >         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
> >         <ser:TypeClass>
> >            
> >            <ser:drugId></ser:drugId>
> >            <ser:drugname></ser:drugname>
> >         </ser:TypeClass>
> >         <ser:TypeClass>
> >            
> >            <ser:drugId></ser:drugId>
> >            <ser:drugname></ser:drugname>
> >         </ser:TypeClass>
> >      </ tem: typeclass>
> >      ...
```

Comment: Do you know the format of the expected data and what you're actually sending?

Comment: It will return a word with type NSString. Yes I know those. I checked them a lot with debug.

Comment: @user3065761: He didn't say the *type* of the data, he said the *format*. By doing `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", someNSMutableArray]`, you use the default NSArray string formatting rather than the format that WCF is expecting. For example, the NSArray might give a string that looks like `(apple, banana, "organic lemon")`, while maybe WCF is expecting an array that looks like `["apple", "banana", "organic lemon"]`. (I don't actually know what WCF wants, but surely you can see there are multiple ways to format a list of things.)

Comment: I have no idea about it through your examples:/ I add some information  to my question to help you understand.

Comment: @user3065761 I find the follow statement unclear: "When I test the parameters with the exactly the same values." You did this in your Objective-C code? If so, perhaps you can show us the code in which you created this properly formatted request. Right now, it's really hard for us to deduce what format the request must take, and your clarification only made it far more confusing (for me, at least), as I'm unsure as how to reconcile your initial question (which appears to try to create a JSON request) with the subsequent SOAP example in your revised question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the basis of your original question's `@"{\"parameter1\":\"%@\"}"` format string, I assumed you were trying to build a JSON request. But that's probably not the best way to create JSON request, so my original answer (below) was focusing on how to properly build that JSON request.

But to step back, there are at least three different types of common web service interfaces:

- JSON, which I (perhaps incorrectly) inferred you wanted on the basis of your original question, hence my original answer, below;
- XML, which your revised question suggests you might want for your SOAP request; or
- some standard HTTP request (e.g. `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or other common variants).

Regardless of which of these you are trying to do, using `stringWithFormat`, using `%@` for the `NSMutableArray` parameter is undoubtedly incorrect.

So, the question is precisely what format the request needs. If, as your revised question suggests, you need to create a SOAP request, you either need to build that manually, adding the XML tags yourself, or you have to use some library. If you are doing this for Mac OS X, see [Web Services Core Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/UsingWebservices/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000985-CH1-SW1). If you are doing for iOS, you'd have to find a third-party library. Perhaps this Stack Overflow question is a good starting place: [How to access SOAP services from iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/204465/1271826). Or search Stack Overflow for "`[ios] soap request`" and you'll get lots of other hits.

Personally, when testing SOAP services from iOS app, I've built the request manually, but it's clumsy and awkward. If your web service offered a JSON interface, that might be a preferable, as that's an interface with far greater iOS support.

Anyway, my original answer, showing how to build the POST body for a JSON request is below.

---

Original answer:

It's impossible for us to get more specific without more details about the complete format of the request, but if you're just trying to create a JSON request, you'd create that `NSData` using `NSJSONSerialization`, not `stringWithFormat`, e.g. probably do something like:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"parameter1": mynsmutablearraylist,
                             @"parameter2": someOtherObject};
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:0 error:&error];
NSAssert(postData, @"%s: dataWithJSONObject error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
```

You also refer to the "objects and keys of the `mynsmutablearraylist`", but I'm confused by the name (which would suggest that its an `NSMutableArray` and your reference to "objects and keys"). But I'll presume that was an array dictionaries, in which case the above syntax still works. But, again, it's hard to say without knowing precisely what your service is looking for.

I also don't understand why you're creating the `NSMutableData` rendition, but if you're trying to add more parameters to this JSON, you really should add those to the original dictionary first and then use `NSJSONSerialization` once you've completely built your dictionary/array structure that you want in JSON format. For example:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dictionary setObject:mynsmutablearraylist forKey:@"parameter1"];
[dictionary setObject:someOtherObject      forKey:@"parameter2"];
// ... repeat for all of the objects in the dictionary

NSError *error = nil;
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:0 error:&error];
NSAssert(postData, @"%s: dataWithJSONObject error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
```

Comment: So can be the problem that Im trying to convert NSMutableArray to NSString?

Comment: @user3065761 Yes, using `stringWithFormat` with your `NSMutableArray` will certainly not work. I must confess that I'm now thoroughly unclear as to precisely what you need, as your initial question suggested a JSON request, but your revision suggests a SOAP interface. Anyway, I revised my answer to expand on some of these points.

Comment: It had been a long time cause for the other coding problems but I made it work. Thank you @Rob. I created NSMutableDictionary for dataWithJSONObject. And I used NSDictionarys and NSMutableDictionarys inside NSMutableDictionary for the sub elements.