# How to post data from Objective c to webservice C#?

Tags: objective-c, web-services

```
NSMutableString *soapMsg = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
  [soapMsg appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<INSERT xmlns=\"http://viium.com/\">\n"]];

[soapMsg appendString:@"<firstname>"];
 //[soapMsg appendString:actionHTMLString];
 [soapMsg appendString:@"RAHUL"];

[soapMsg appendString:@"</firstname>"];
[soapMsg appendString:@"<lastname>"];
[soapMsg appendString:@"sharma"];
[soapMsg appendString:@"</lastname>"];
[soapMsg appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"</INSERT>"]];
[soapMsg appendString:@"</soap:Body>"];
[soapMsg appendString:@"</soap:Envelope>"];
```

I am having this Xml message how to receive firstname and lastname  in webservice c#??

Comment: [WebMethod] public DataTable INSERT(string firstname, string lastname)
       { }      firstname,lastname showing null

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204465/how-to-access-soap-services-from-iphone